# The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. windows server 2012 R

Tags: c#, excel, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server

I want to import excel so I am using System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
but it give error(Microsoft=errors company),it give that error
**the 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.**

I try google and install 2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components(https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734) and Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable( https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255 )

now it works in my local but in windows server 2012 R it give same error altough I install same .exe

what should I do?

Comment: ACE is part of Microsoft Office.  Usually 2012 R doesn't have Office.  The ACE drive is downloadable from MSDN and doesn't required Office License.  I've never go it to work on PCs without Office.  Other people have claimed to get ACE to work without office.

Comment: Does your server already have Office on it?  If so, check 32/64 bit.  I have had problems with ACE where I needed 32 Bit drivers and Office was pre-installed with 64 Bit.

Comment: Can you give me ACE drive for windows server 2012 R please...I installed this   2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components(https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734) and Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable( https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255 )

Comment: @JonathanWillcock my server 64 bit and I install this

Comment: 2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components(https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734) and Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable( https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255 )

Comment: I was not asking whether your server was 64Bit.  I was asking whether it had a 32Bit or 64 Bit version of Office.  From experience you can only have one ACE runtime and that has to be the same Bitness as any other Office applications that are already installed.

Comment: should I install office?

Comment: @jdweng can you give me ACE drive downloadeble link please for 64 bit windows server 2012 R

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: Office Licenses for 2012 R I've been told are expensive since it is a multi-user operating system.  You don't normally install office on a server.

Comment: Thank you @JonathanWillcock and jdweng it works now,Allah razı olsun :)